# jquery.scrollto is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, scrollto

I'm trying to use jquery.scrollto on my react app but cannot seem to use it correctly.

I installed it via npm

```
>npm install jquery.scrollto
+ jquery.scrollto@2.1.2
added 1 package in 5.316s
```

but when I try to use it I get a typeError

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollTo is not a function
```

Here's the code inside the application :

```
var $ = require('jquery')
require('jquery.scrollto')

$('#home').on('click',function(){
  $(window).scrollTo('#home', 1000);
})
```

and here's my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery.scrollto": "^2.1.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: React uses a "Virtual DOM" which jQuery can not "read" from - so you should do it like the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element

Comment: the plugin you're using uses the syntax within the onclick function. Did you attempt just $(window).scrollTo( '#home", 1000)?

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes I have, and I wouldn't work. However I found where was the problem, apparently when used with react, jquery.scrollto does not need to be nested in jquery but can be used independently. I'll post the whole process below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries, I found out how to make it work.

I was requiring scrollto as such : `require('jquery.scrollto')` and then calling it via the jquery's `$()`. Apparently it is not the way to go when `scrollTo` is installed via npm. What I did was the following :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var scrollTo = require('jquery.scrollto');

// inside react's componentDidMount : 
$('#testbutton').on('click',scrollto(0,500))
```

I had no idea that scrollto didn't need to be nested in jquery.

Also, I realised it was innefective to use string refs, I advice people reading this thread to visit  [ReactJS how to scroll to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element) for additional informations. Thanks  and credits to @davidbucka