# How to access nth parent node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to get height of the parent div of children elements.[image]

I have a `Parent` div with class="Parent" this have also `n` children element like `<div data-elementid="el_ryz-E9a349" class="row">`

`Parent` have a fix `height: 220px` and I need to know if children element (n) `<div data-elementid="el_ryz-E9a349" class="row">` appear in parrent height if not execute `scrollIntoView()` to this children.

Important I can't delete this both elements, empty `div` and `<div class="container"` because affects my design.

```
...
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    const elementNode = document.querySelector(`[data-elementid='${action.payload.id}']`);
    const parentElementNode = elementNode.parentNode;
    const elementsHeight = parentElementNode.offsetHeight;
    const menuContainer = parentElementNode.parentNode.offsetHeight;

    if (elementsHeight > menuContainer) {
      elementNode.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'end',
      });
    }

 };
setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 200);
...
```

It's obvious if I've `n` children elements it's redundant to make `elementNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` to access Parent node to get height property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function to go up in your element parents and search for you parent classname:

```
const getParent = (element, cls) => {
    if (element && element.parentElement) {
        const parentClassName = element.parentElement.className;
        if (element.parentElement && parentClassName && parentClassName.match(new RegExp(cls, 'g'))) {
            return element.parentElement; // Found it
        }
        getParent(element.parentElement, cls);
    } else {
        return false; // No parent with such a className
    }
}

const scrollToBottom = () => {
    const elementNode = document.querySelector(`[data-elementid='${action.payload.id}']`);
    const parentElementNode = getParent(elementNode, 'parent'); // second arg is the parent classname you looking for.

    if (parentElementNode) {
        const elementsHeight = parentElementNode.offsetHeight;
        const menuContainer = parentElementNode.parentNode.offsetHeight;

        if (elementsHeight > menuContainer) {
            elementNode.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'end',
            });
        }
    }

    console.log('no parent found!')

};

setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 200);
```

Select with data-atttribute:

```
const getParentWithAttr = (element, attr) => {
    if (element && element.parentElement) {
        const parentElement = element.parentElement;
        if (parentElement && parentElement.getAttribute('data-attr') === attr) {
            return parentElement; // Found it
        }
        getParent(parentElement, attr);
    } else {
        return false; // No parent with such a className
    }
}
```

Use case should be like this:

```
<div id="..." class="..." data-attr="parent">// parrent
    ... // chilren
</div>


getParentWithAttr(document.querySelector('.element'), 'parent');
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, I can't work with `classnames`, in development mode it works 100% but in production classNames are hashed. That's why I work with data-attributes and querySelector to get that node. I need to use this function in two place in my page and the children of parent is not in same order.

Comment: Ok then, just replace the className with dataAttr and define that function in the global and just import it where you wanna use it. You'll be fine.

Comment: I added an example with `data-attr` at the end of my answer. hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question's tag says React.js, I would instead refer to [ReactJS how to scroll to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element). This uses React refs and makes your code much simpler. That being said, it looks like the question is actually using pure JavaScript on static HTML.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class SampleComponent extends Component {
  scrollToDomRef = () => {
    const myDomNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.myRef.current)
    myDomNode.scrollIntoView()
  };

  render() {
    return <> // '<></>' is a React 16.3.0+ feature, use <div> if previous
      <button onClick={this.scrollToDomRef}>Click me</div>
      <div ref={ re => { this.myRef = re } }></div>
    </>
  }
}
```