# How to scroll to an element with hooks/functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element) again but ask now how I can achieve this using functions/hooks.

I've tried to use useRef and then access the offset form current.offsetTop, however I'm struggling accessing this ref after the component was mounted.

```
function ScrollComponent(props) {
  const foo = false; //loading method
  let resultsRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      behavior: "smooth",
      top: resultsRef.current.offsetTop
    });
  }, [resultsRef]);

  if (foo)
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Loading...</h4>
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <div ref={resultsRef}>
      <h4>content</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above example, I have a const called foo which doesn't need to have this scroll ref attached to as it shows when the content is loading.

However, when running this code I get Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined

In my useEffect method, I specify the dependency as the resultsRef so I expect it to only be called when the resultsRef gets written to when the content div loads, however, this is not the case.

Comment: Are you cool with using a class-based component?

Comment: No @ChristopherNgo I asked for help using functions and hooks, if I was using classes I'd use the previous question I linked to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before you attach your ref to the div `ref.current` is undefined, add an if check in your effect to check if it's not undefined.

also, we should listen to the `isLoading` state instead of the ref object.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(
  () => {
    if (resultsRef.current) {
      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: "smooth",
        top: resultsRef.current.offsetTop
      });
    }
  },
  [isLoading]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then the code never gets called. the useEffect code gets called when the loading return is called but not when the content is called.

Comment: Ah my bad we should add loading as our dependency instead of resultRef, will edit in a sec.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Why do I need to use loading as a dependency? when isn't the thing changing the ref object?