# Typescript Error in React useScroll hook: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following function definition:

```
const useScroll = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    function executeScroll() {
        if (ref !== null)
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop)
    }

    const htmlElementAttributes = { ref }

    return [executeScroll, htmlElementAttributes]
}

export default useScroll;
```

Based on this function, I have the following code:

```
const [executeScroll, scrollHtmlAttributes] = useScroll();

const click_argueBtn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    executeScroll();//error
}
```

However, the `executeScroll();` code throws the following error:

```
Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

Any ideas why I receive this error? My code is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828976/1845408).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is doing its best to determine the types automatically, and it determines that useScroll returns an array, who's elements are each `() => void | { ref: /*ref type*/ }`  (i don't know precisely what the type on the ref object is). When you try to call executeScroll, it doesn't know whether it's a function, or an object with a ref. So since it might not be a function, you're not allowed to call it.

Instead, i'd recommend explicitly telling typescript that useScroll returns a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple). A tuple is similar to an array, except you explicitly declare how many elements it has and what their individual types are:

```
const useScroll = (): [() => void, { ref: /* ref type */ }] => {
  // ...etc
}
```

or

```
const useScroll = () => {
  // ... etc
  return [executeScroll, htmlElementAttributes] as [() => void, { ref: /* ref type */ }];
}
```

or if you don't like it inline, you could extract it to a type:

```
export type UseScrollResult = [() => void, { ref: /* ref type */ }];
const useScroll = (): UseScrollResult => {
  // ...etc
}
```

From this, typescript now knows that element 0 of the array is `() => void`, and therefore it's legal to call it as a function.