# Creating smooth scroll in React (browser friendly)

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, cross-browser

I am currently building my site in react. However the `refs scroll`/`css` is not compatible with safari and some other browsers. Meaning in safari it just jumps to a div instead of scrolling to it.

**Not compatible**

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

What is the best library (that is active) or method to create an all browser (latest versions) smooth scroll functionality. I do not want it to be too heavy because it will be used often.

This is what my current scroll is based on: [ReactJS how to scroll to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Comment: Hi have you simply tried the native `window.scrollTo()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo ?

Comment: @t3__rry The native `window.scrollTo()` isn't a smooth transition. Also the extra options on it that enable it to be smooth are not compatible with safari.