# How to refer to a part of the html block in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

So, I want to refer to a particular part of a page, in react js
as we do using a `<a href="#some_ID_of_div"> Link </a>`.

But when I do it using an `<a>` anchor tag, the page is getting reloaded.
I dont want the page to reload and scroll down to that required part of the page.

For example, open reactjs documentation. : [ReactDocs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

and scroll down, There you see a Try React Heading, just as we hover on it, we do see a link icon , and clicking on it, we just scroll down and Try React Heading is the top part of the Page now.

Is there a way we can achieve that using the `<Link>from React-Router-Dom </Link>`

I want that feature, in react without reloading the page.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You would like to do scroll too element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS how to scroll to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Comment: yes, more of a scroll, or refer to it. @Jo

Comment: If the part you want to refer to is in the same project, use it as a common component. If not, perhaps `micro-service` would be an option