# Reactjs Scroll to first error on form submission of a large form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, js-scrollintoview

I am using react with Material UI and typescript and have a form. On form submission if inputs have validation error i would like to scroll to the first input with the validation error. I have pasted the simple form code below which inject validation error in the town input on submission. In reality error could be in any or multiple inputs.

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField, Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const ScrollTest = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<{ town: string; county: string }>({
    town: '',
    county: '',
  });

  const [error, setError] = useState({ town: '', county: '' });

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const errorVal = !value ? `${name} is requied` : '';
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
    setError({ ...error, [name]: errorVal });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!state.town) {
      setError({ ...error, town: 'Town input is required' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} noValidate>
        <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <TextField
              error={!!error.town}
              variant='outlined'
              fullWidth
              id='town'
              label='Town'
              name='town'
              autoComplete='town'
              placeholder='Town *'
              value={state.town || ''}
              onChange={handleChange}
              helperText={error.town}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <TextField
              error={!!error.county}
              variant='outlined'
              fullWidth
              id='county'
              label='County'
              name='county'
              autoComplete='county'
              placeholder='County'
              value={state.county || ''}
              onChange={handleChange}
              helperText={error.county}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <TextField
              variant='outlined'
              fullWidth
              id='county2'
              label='County2'
              name='county2'
              autoComplete='county2'
              placeholder='County2'
              value={state.county || ''}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>{' '}
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>{' '}
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>{' '}
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>{' '}
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>{' '}
        <br></br> <br></br> <br></br>
        <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center'>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Button type='submit' fullWidth variant='contained' color='primary'>
              Update profile
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default ScrollTest;
```

Any idea how to scroll to the first input with the validation error.

Answer (score 7):

```
                             <Button
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    const err = Object.keys(errors);
                                    if (err.length) {
                                        const input = document.querySelector(
                                            `input[name=${err[0]}]`
                                        );

                                        input.scrollIntoView({
                                            behavior: 'smooth',
                                            block: 'center',
                                            inline: 'start',
                                        });
                                    }
                                    submitForm();
                                }}
                            >
                                {isSubmitting ? (
                                    <CircularProgress size={22} />
                                ) : (
                                    'Submit'
                                )}
                            </Button>
```

This is the easiest thing you can do to scroll into the first error in a big form using Formik, I did this inside Formik submit button, where `errors` object and `submitForm()` function comes from Formik

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the reference of the input where you are getting error and you can scroll to that reference, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/reactjs-how-to-scroll-to-an-element) I think

Comment: The problem i have is that my form is large and contains child components having inputs. Any idea if i can scroll to view using class or an id? Or how to pass refs between parent and child?

Comment: okay you can use `element = document.getElementById("the_id")` and `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});`, I think you are looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this easily is by using [React Hook Form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/)

And utilize [`shouldFocusError`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#shouldFocusError) option when initializing `useForm` hook

For example:

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ shouldFocusError: true })
```

Comment: This is not working