# How to scroll up while selecting rowsperpage in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React and material UI. I want when the user changes rowperpage from drop-down than I want to scroll at the top of my window.
 I have used Table in which for pagination I have written code like-

```
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
            component="div"
            count={users.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}

          />
```

functions called are written like this

```
const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setPage(newPage);

  };


  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
window.scrollTo(0,0);   
  };
```

I tried using window.scrollTo(0,0), for handleChangePage its working but for handleChangePerPage its not working.

Comment: <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
            component="div"
            count={users.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            
          />

Answer (score 3):

After digging for three hours I found that you have to add the following prop to the`tablePagination` component as well as adding the ref as per other great answers explained ([How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)):

SelectProps(https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/f013f19bc2792a25663e8a3658aed0365c0a1964/packages/material-ui/src/TablePagination/TablePagination.js#L118) and I use scrollIntoView instead of scrollTo option.

So change your code to the following it should work:

```
  const tableRef = React.useRef(null)
...

<TableContainer component={Paper} ref={tableRef}>
...

<TablePagination
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
            component="div"
            count={users.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            SelectProps={{
          inputProps: { "aria-label": "rows per page" },
          native: true
        }}

          />
```

```
const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    tableRef.current && tableRef.current.scrollIntoView();

    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
    setPage(0)
  }
```