# React Native: Passing Ref from Parent to Child in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Have tried a few different approaches and can't figure out the exact syntax to pass a ref from the parent to the child. Ultimately I'm trying to make it so that I can scroll to beginning onPress of a Child component. Can someone help me figure it out?

Getting error: `scrollViewRef.scrollTo is not a function'

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';

const Parent = () => {

  const scrollViewRef = useRef();

  const scrollToBeginning = () => {
    scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={ scrollViewRef }
      pagingEnabled
      snapToInterval={ width }
      horizontal
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      scrollEnabled={ true }
    >
      <Child
        scrollToBeginning={ scrollToBeginning }
      >
    </ScrollView>
  )
}


const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button onPress={ props.scrollToBeginning } title="Scroll To Beginning" />
  )
}
```

Comment: Function `scrollTo()` does not exist directly on ref.

you must use `window.scrollTo` or `ref.current.scrollTo`

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });` since the ref property is assigned to the current variable within ref object

```
const Parent = () => {

  const scrollViewRef = useRef();

  const scrollToBeginning = () => {
    scrollViewRef..current.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={ scrollViewRef }
      pagingEnabled
      snapToInterval={ width }
      horizontal
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      scrollEnabled={ true }
    >
      <Child
        scrollToBeginning={ scrollToBeginning }
      >
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```