# Scroll to an element in a different, scrollable div in React using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to scroll an element to view when a callback is called in a separate div.

I'm following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element) which seems to work if the element is in the same div, but if the reference is to an element in a different div, is does not work.

React Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-carson-w8o46?file=/src/App.js

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to scroll the window, but you need to scroll the parent block. Inspect the elements through the developer tools and see.

```
const scrollToRef = ref => {
  ref.current.parentElement.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
};
```