# Scroll to a component When I create it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll, ref

I have a Parent component with two Children component inside. In one of the children I have a form, in the other one I have a List(I map over it to get each individual item).

When I submit that form It will create an "item" inside that List.

What I would like to achive is: when I submit the form to scroll to that new item that is created inside the List. I am using a functional approach in case that someone wants to put an exemple, if not I would be more than happy with the theory behind it to make it like a reactive way.

I have tried this but it isn't the exact thing of what I want. I did also try with useRef, but it keeps telling me that it is undefined

```
function topFunction() {
    document.documentElement.scrollBy(0, -1000);
  }
```

Comment: I think this is a valid solution to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element

Comment: And also can you add the code where you used useRef