# How to scroll to a functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, jsx

I am new to Reactjs. I have functional component that has Title defined, now i want scroll to be implemented when a user clicks on the title, user should be scrolled to appropriate functional component in the same page below

```
const Page = () => {

  return (
    <div>
         <div>
            About Us
        </div>
        <div>
            Contact Us
        </div>
        <AboutUs/>
        <ContactUs/>
   </div>
  );
};
```

In the above code scrolling should happpen when user clicks on About Us or Contact Us

Can someone please help me in implementing the scrolling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

Same old HTML technique can be used here. Point the link of your About or Contact us section, to the id of the wrapper element of that particular section.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            // content...
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const About = () => {
    return (
        <div id='about'>
            // content...
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### You can use Routing to consume multiple pages functionality in SPAs. Check out [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)