# React pass ref throw functional components in different levels

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to scroll to menu element in a page.

I have the menu component which is not a parent of components to which I would like to scroll.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element) that describe a similar problem

> #### Passing ref to a child We want the ref to be attached to a dom element, not to a react component. So when passing it to a child
>
> component we can't name the prop ref.
>
> ````
>     const myRef = useRef(null)
>     return <ChildComp refProp={myRef}></ChildComp> }  ```
>
> Then attach the ref prop to a dom element. ```jsx const ChildComp =
> (props) => {
>     return <div ref={props.refProp} /> } ```
> ````

Here's my app structure

Menu component:

```
const MenuApp = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="desktop-menu">
                <div className="menu-item a-propos">
                    <p className='button'>Me découvrir</p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item competences">
                    <p className='button'>Compétences </p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item experiences">
                    <p className='button'>Experiences</p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item formation">
                    <p className='button'>Formation </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The parent is app component

```
 <div className="App">
  <div className="hero">
    <HeaderApp />
    <ApprochApp />
  </div>
  <Apropos />
  <Competences />
  <Experiences />
  <Formation />
  <Recom />
  <Contact />
  <Footer />
 </div >
```

I would like that mu menus scrolls to the react components in the main `App` component

So how can I passe the reference from the menu component to the app and use it in components to scroll ?

Comment: Have you looked at [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem completely though. However, one thing I can see from your question is that you're not forwarding the `ref` properly.

What you need in this case is `forwardRef`.

Basically, what you need to do is to create the `childComponent` as something like this:

```
const childComponent = React.forwardRef(({...otherProps}, ref) => {
  return (<><div ref={ref}>Component content </div></>)
})
```

Where you need to use the component all you need to do is this:

```
const parentComponent = () => {
  const reveiwsRef = React.useRef("");
  return (
   <div> 
      <childComponent ref={reviewsRef} />
   </div>
  );
}
```

You can find more info about this on the react documentation: [Forwarding-Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

I have hope this helps though

Comment: what I would like to do is the scroll throw a page when clicking a menu element. The menu component is not a child neither a parent of elements component to scroll to

Comment: Ohhhhh, you want to conditionally render a component when a button/menu item is clicked? Please confirm if this is the case

Comment: I want to scroll to an element of a page when click on an element of an horizontal menu elements , like a  one page portfolio menu " about me , skills , work " then automatically scroll when click on menu elemy

Comment: wow, really, Have you tried to use anchor tags for this?
Identify the target with an id, and then place an anchor tag with the href having a key of the intended `id` as the value. something like this: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html