# How to scroll and expand an Accordion by onClick on an icon from a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, semantic-ui-react

I have a component `MainContent`with its child Component `AddMock`. There is a table in `MainContent` which shows some list of items. It has a certain action on each row like view and edit which are rendered by Icons by semantic-UI react. By clicking on each icon, I need to scroll up and expand an accordion. The accordion is in `AddMock`.

```html
// AddMock.js
const AddMock = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <Accordion style={{ paddingLeft: "32px" }}>
        <Card className="collapseStyle">
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Add Mock
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              <Container className="mockbody">
                <Header as="h3">Hierarchy</Header>
                <TabContent />
              </Container>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Below is the MainContent.js

```html
const MainContent = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <AddMock />
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-header card-header-info">
                <h4 className="card-title ">MOCK</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <form>
                  {loading ? (
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>AppName</th>
                            <th>Parent_App</th>
                            <th>Created_Date</th>
                            <th>Req_Path</th>
                            <th>Resp_Code</th>
                            <th>Resp_Content_Type</th>
                            <th>Resp_Delay</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          {data.map((routes, index) => {
                            return routes.map(contents, index);
                          })}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <Spinner
                      animation="border"
                      style={{ marginLeft: "620px" }}
                    />
                  )}
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to implement this with window.scrollTo() or any other better way to implement this in react?

Comment: I think you can use refs in this situation. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element

Comment: @kubilaysalih: Can you give an example on how can I add this in my case?

Comment: here example: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-platform-q6fnx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark also check this library. you can use ref version with smooth animations https://github.com/ganderzz/react-scroll-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Ref

To start things off, we can have a state that keeps the `eventKey` of the active Accordion

```
const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState("");
```

After that, we use a `ref` for our React-Bootstrap Accordion component. We need to use [Forwarded Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) later on to at least assign a ref to the topmost DOM element of the Accordion component so we can scroll to it.

As for the Icon, take a look at its `onClick` event, this simply sets the `activeKey` to `"0"` which is mapped with your `Accordion.Collapse` component's `eventKey`. This will serve as the trigger point for its "expanding".

```
// we are going to need a ref to the Accordion element go get its position/use the scrollIntoView function
const accordElem = useRef(null);

const handleClickEdit = () => {
  setActiveKey("0"); // "0" here is as defined in your Accordion.Collapse eventKey
  accordElem.current.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "end",
    inline: "nearest"
  }); // initiate scroll to the "AddMock" Accordion component
};

return (
  <div>
    <AddMock
      activeKey={activeKey}
      setActiveKey={setActiveKey}
      ref={accordElem}
    />

    ...

    <Icon
      name="pencil"
      size="huge"
      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      onClick={() => handleClickEdit("0")}
    />
```

For the scrolling we can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView. In addition, there are of course other alternatives such as [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Finally, here is how our Accordion component looks like with the forwarded ref & utilization of the `activeKey` prop taken from the parent state:

```
const AddMock = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // optional re-toggling of expanded accordion
  function handleClickToggle(eventKey) {
    if (eventKey === props.activeKey) {
      props.setActiveKey("");
    } else {
      props.setActiveKey(eventKey);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="row" ref={ref}>
      <Accordion style={{ paddingLeft: "32px" }} activeKey={props.activeKey}>
        <Card className="collapseStyle">
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle
              as={Button}
              variant="link"
              eventKey="0"
              onClick={() => handleClickToggle("0")}
            >
              Add Mock
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              ...
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-semantic-ui-react-bootstrap-3ndyl?file=/src/App.js:2444-3230