# Vertical Stepper should scroll to top when changing steps in Material UI react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Vertical Stepper in material ui should scroll to the beginning of the selected step when changing step

[image]

One solution probably is to use ref to scroll to the stepper titles
[How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

is there any better solution?

Material ui version 4.11.0

Answer (score 3):

Just do a useEffect() on the variable that sets your step count and then in that useEffect i.e.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('changed step scrolling to top of window');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [activeStep])
```