# How to go to last element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, reload

I tried `scrollIntoView` and used `.lastchild` but I can't go to the latest comment. Used `window.scrollTo` too can't find any solution.

Can anyone have some suggestions on what will work?

```
     const click = () => {
                fetch('url')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.affectedRows > 0) {
                       var element = document.getElementById("txt").lastChild;
                        element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "center"});
                 }
            })
        }         
}

 {getComment.map(cmnt =>
                        <div key={cmnt.comment_id} className="article-comments-reply">
                            <div className="text-box" id="txt">
                                <h3>{cmnt.username}</h3>
                                <div className="reply-box">
                                    <h4>{cmnt.comment_text}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
)}
```

Comment: your fetch is just returning the data, are you trying to get the last item fetched ? because last child method won't do that

Comment: This method solves my problem.. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use last child. It is also not the best solution in React to use tools to get an element by selector.

Just set the parent element's `scrollTop` to its `height`.
It looks like this:

```js
ref.current.scrollTop = ref.current.scrollHeight;
```

And this `ref` should point to your **parent component** in which this code is wrapped:

```
{getComment.map(cmnt =>
  <div key={cmnt.comment_id} className="article-comments-reply">
      <div className="text-box" id="txt">
          <h3>{cmnt.username}</h3>
          <div className="reply-box">
              <h4>{cmnt.comment_text}</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
)}
```

If you want to add `scrollBehavior` via `js`, you can use something like this:

```
ref.current.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';
```

As a result, it can be easily transferred into a `custom hook` that can perform smooth scrolling on any element.

Custom hook `useScrollToBottom`.

```js
export const useScrollToBottom = (ref) => {
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    ref.current.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';
    ref.current.scrollTop = ref.current.scrollHeight;
  };

  return {
    scrollToBottom,
  }
}
```

Using

```js
// ...
const ref = useRef();
const {scrollToBottom} = useScrollToBottom(ref);

useEffect(() => {
  // scroll when you need
  scrollToBottom();
}, []);

return (
  <div ref={ref} className="list">
    {
      // some elements
    }
  </div>
)
// ...
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. I get this error.

Comment: @ShahariarRahmanSajib, try this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-grass-l461g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function from any component you want this code will target your last child.

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    let targetLastElement = document.getElementsByClassName('classNameOfTileWhichYouWantToTarget');
    targetLastElement = targetLastElement[targetLastElement.length - 1]
    targetLastElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
```