# React: scroll to form when its set visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want my browser to jump to the div tag of my form that is displayed when state is set to true on button click, however best I can get is jump to focus which wont be good when user clicks button  and the form first field is visible on the page already. I tried adding

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
```

on my component constructor and

```
this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
```

on the showForm method and I have ref on the div I want to jump to:

```
<div ref={this.myRef}>
```

How can I make it jump to the myRef div (making it be at the top after clicking it)?

Comment: Hello , see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828976/14522591) may be ti will helps