# how to scroll div using onClick in react js?

Tags: reactjs

hello everyone I am new at reactjs.

I want to scroll specific div instead of window

```
          const handleScroll = (event) => {
      window.scrollBy(100, 0);
      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `useRef` hook to give a reference that the component you want to scroll using React functional components. Then use `scrollIntoView` to give a smooth scrolling behavior.

Here is a example:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
const titleRef = useRef();

function handleClick() {
  titleRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}

return (
  <article>
    <h1 ref={titleRef}>A React article for Latin readers</h1>
    Here is the content
    <br />
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to the top</button>
  </article>
);
}
```

Comment: You can mark as an acceptable answer   if this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this js code

```
import React from "react";
const App = () => {
   const myRef = React.useRef(null)

   const scrollDiv = () => myRef.current.scrollIntoView()    

   return (
      <> 
         <div ref={myRef}>Hello World</div> 
         <button onClick={scrollDiv }> Scroll </button> 
      </>
   )
}
```

Or

```
import React from "react";
const App = () => {
    const [scrollDiv, myRef] = React.useScroll()
    useEffect(executeScroll, []) 
    
    return (
             <div ref={myRef}>Hello World</div>
           ); 
}
```

Or

Instead of using js code use css for that.

```
<div className="list_item">
     <ul>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
              .
              .
              .
         <li>...</li>
     </ul>                         
 </div>
```

In your css file just use like this...

```
.list_item {
      overflow: auto;
}
```

If you want styled scroll use below code

```
.list_item {
      overflow: auto;
}
.list_item::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       background-color: light-gray;
}

.list_item::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 3px;
      background-color: light-gray;
}

.list_item::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: dark-gray;
}
```

Comment: thanks for participating but here I want to use onclick  method on the button