# Can I use document.getElementByID in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am having a songKey array as a STATE. Its data populates from API.
I am rendering JSX using this array data.
I like to add useRef in order to refer elements from the JSX. Is it possible to add useRef hooks via code automatically ?
or shall I use document.getElementById() function to refer elements ?

```
  const [songKey, songKeyController] = useState([]);
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  const renderLyrics = () => {
    let lyrics = [];
    if (songKey) {
      lyrics = songKey.map((key) => (
        <div key={key} className={`lyrics_container ${key}`}>
          <div className="lyrics_data tamil-font">
            {props.currentSong.Data[key]}
          </div>
        </div>
      ));
    }
    return lyrics;
  };
```

Comment: are you trying to access dom elements directly ?

Comment: I need to scroll element while clicking on the navigation link.,

Comment: if you trying to select elements in same level of single parent use hook in parent then select child with `querySelectorAll` to have reference to all child elements so you can access all childs with one hook if i understand it right

Comment: I guess You can use useref like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828976/2290153

Answer (score -1):

I dont recommend using dom elements directly in React but if you are using it anyways then you can do it in way

use `useRef` in parent element then simply use `querySelectorAll` then use childs with index value of that array to access them directly

see the [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-3mid5d?file=/src/samples/Main.jsx:0-784)

**main.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Main() {
  const EL = useRef(null);

  const [data, setData] = useState(["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const childs = EL.current.querySelectorAll(".child");

    // fun demo
    let index = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      const curr = childs[index % childs.length];
      childs.forEach((each) => (each.style.background = ""));
      curr.style.background = "red";
      console.log(curr);
      index++;
    }, 1000);
    // fun demo

  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="root" ref={EL}>
      {data.map((each, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="child" key={i}>
            {each}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```