# Scroll to specific position in page - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a simple action, that when the page loads, the page will scroll to a certain position.

But no matter what I do, the action does not fire.

Is there another way to do this in a React app?

for example:

`window.scrollBy(0, 850);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

wrap it inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollBy(0, 850);
}, []);
```

that way, it runs when the page mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this through a ref

Steps

1. Create a ref with useRef()
2. Assign that ref to the element you want to scroll to
   3.Create a useEffect inside that useEffect add this code

```html
useEffect(() => {
ref.current.scrollIntoView()
} ,[])
```

The same thing applies if you want to just scroll to a certain height, you can just wrap it in a useEffect that fires when the component is mounted