# Jump to section works on second click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in Navbar I have on "Skills Section" an onClick event. When I click on "Skills", onClick works, but it stops the page from jumping to section.

TSX Navbar:

```
const [skillsClicked, setSkillsClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
    const handleClickSkills = () =>{
        setSkillsClicked(!skillsClicked);
    }
    <a href="#skills" >
        <li onClick={handleClickSkills}>Skills</li>
    </a>
```

TSX Skills:

```
const {skillsClicked, handleClickSkills} = useGlobalContext();

return (
        <section>
            <div>
                <ul id='skills'></ul>
                    
            </div>
        </section>
    )
```

I want when I click on "Skills", the onClick event to change the state and in the same time to jump on the section based on the ID. (Separately they both work fine)

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const [skillsClicked, setSkillsClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleClickSkills = () =>{
    setSkillsClicked(!skillsClicked);
    document.getElementById("skills").scrollIntoView({
        behavior : "smooth"
    })
}

// some code in between

<div onClick={handleClickSkills}>
    <li>Skills</li>
</div>

// or:
<li onClick={handleClickSkills}>
    Skills
</li>
```